# Deleting reversed duplicates with R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data frame in **R** that contains the gene ids of paralogous genes in Arabidopsis, looking something like this:

```
gene_x    gene_y
AT1       AT2
AT3       AT4
AT1       AT2
AT1       AT3
AT2       AT1
```

with the 'ATx' corresponding to the gene names.

Now, for downstream analysis, I would want to continue only with the unique pairs. Some pairs are just simple duplicates and can be removed easily upon using the `duplicated()` function.
However, the fifth row in the artificial data frame above is also a duplicate, but in reversed order, and which will not be picked up by the `duplicated()`, nor by the `unique()` function.

Any ideas in how to remove these rows?

Comment: Sort first, then find duplicates. I suggest you provide us a with a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
mydf <- read.table(text="gene_x    gene_y
AT1       AT2
AT3       AT4
AT1       AT2
AT1       AT3
AT2       AT1", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Here's one strategy using `apply`, `sort`, `paste`, and `duplicated`:

```
mydf[!duplicated(apply(mydf,1,function(x) paste(sort(x),collapse=''))),]
  gene_x gene_y
1    AT1    AT2
2    AT3    AT4
4    AT1    AT3
```

And here's a slightly different solution:

```
mydf[!duplicated(lapply(as.data.frame(t(mydf), stringsAsFactors=FALSE), sort)),]
  gene_x gene_y
1    AT1    AT2
2    AT3    AT4
4    AT1    AT3
```

Comment: Be careful! By using `collapse=''` you may unintentionally delete some non-duplicated gene pairs. For example, `ABC` - `DE` pair will be deleted if there are `AB` - `CDE` pair (since they both form `ABCDE` when pasted together). So, by changing `collapse=''` to `collapse='_'` this solution works perfectly.

Comment: How would you change the code to exclude also the first observation of a duplicate, i.e. to keep only rows 2 and 3 of the original data frame in the output?

Answer (score 12):

A `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
mydf %>%
 group_by(grp = paste(pmax(gene_x, gene_y), pmin(gene_x, gene_y), sep = "_")) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)

  gene_x gene_y
  <chr>  <chr> 
1 AT1    AT2   
2 AT1    AT3   
3 AT3    AT4
```

Or:

```
mydf %>%
 group_by(grp = paste(pmax(gene_x, gene_y), pmin(gene_x, gene_y), sep = "_")) %>%
 filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)
```

Or:

```
mydf %>%
 group_by(grp = paste(pmax(gene_x, gene_y), pmin(gene_x, gene_y), sep = "_")) %>%
 distinct(grp, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)
```

Or using `dplyr` and `purrr`:

```
mydf %>%
 group_by(grp = paste(invoke(pmax, .), invoke(pmin, .), sep = "_")) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)
```

And as of `purrr 0.3.0` `invoke()` is retired, `exec()` should be used instead:

```
mydf %>%
 group_by(grp = paste(exec(pmax, !!!.), exec(pmin, !!!.), sep = "_")) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(grp = paste(sort(c(gene_x, gene_y)), collapse = "_")) %>%
 group_by(grp) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another tidyverse-centric approach but using `purrr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

c_sort_collapse <- function(...){
  c(...) %>% 
    sort() %>% 
    str_c(collapse = ".")
}

mydf %>% 
  mutate(x_y = map2_chr(gene_x, gene_y, c_sort_collapse)) %>% 
  distinct(x_y, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-x_y)
#>   gene_x gene_y
#> 1    AT1    AT2
#> 2    AT3    AT4
#> 3    AT1    AT3
```