# How to speed up the process of finding reversed rows in a data table

Tags: r, data.table, reverse

Given a `data.table` in R, I want to find rows that are the reversed version of a previous row. For example:

```
>head(DT)
   V1      V2 
 1 nameA   nameB 
 2 nameA   nameC
 3 nameB   nameA
 4 nameB   nameF
 5 nameN   nameP
 6 nameP   nameN
```

In the case of `row 1`, the code should return `row 3`. In the case of `row 5`, the code should return `row 6`. Eventually, I want to drop the "reversed" rows.

The real dataset has 0.5 million rows and 2 columns. At the moment I am using this piece of code, which does the job:

```
require(foreach)
require(doMC)
registerDoMC(4)
rm.idx <- c()
rm.idx <- foreach(i=1:nrow(DT), .combine = 'c')%dopar%{
       if (!(i %in% rm.idx)) which(DT[i,1] == DT[,2] & DT[i,2] == DT[,1])
}
```

The code "returns" a vector (`rm.idx`) that contains the indexes to those rows that are the reversed version of a previous row.

However, it takes a long time (more than 30min) for the relatively "small" size of the data set. I often find that R has some tweak or some function that does the trick much faster (or, also, that my code is not very efficient). Therefore, I am wondering if anyone knows **a faster way of finding rows that are the reversed of a previous row**.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Does it need to be only the immediately preceding row, or any row that came before it?

Comment: @AndrewTaylor: Hi Andrew. No it does not. If you see the example data table I showed in the question, the first index returned by the code would have to be `3`, because `row 3` is the same as `reversed(row 1)`, and of course,  `row 1` is not immediately preceding `row 3` . Overall, "any row that came before it" is fine for me. Thanks

Comment: How do the answers over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756392/deleting-reversed-duplicates-with-r) compare to what you have, in terms of speed?

Comment: Using foreach() here will massively SLOW your processing.

Comment: Do you have only two columns, or you might have more?

Comment: @LauriK. I did try without it and 10000 rows and it was faster...but I will try again.

Comment: @MaratTalipov: only two

Comment: Do you want to drop those rows in the end?

Comment: @docendodiscimus: yes, sorry, I should have specified this in the question. I have just edited it including a relevant sentence, but overall, yes, I do want to get rid of it.

Comment: @AndrewTaylor. Thanks, the answer here works for me in no time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756392/deleting-reversed-duplicates-with-r

Comment: Try `DT[!duplicated(paste(pmin(V1, V2),pmax(V1,V2)))]`

Comment: @akrun: thanks, this is very similar to the answer that Andrew pointed before and also works. Thanks again.

Comment: @Javier But, I think this should be faster because of `pmax`, `pmin`

Comment: @akrun: just tried, it is!, thanks! (btw, note that you are missing a coma before the last `]`) :) . Many thanks

Comment: @Javier Actually, my solution was in `data.table`.  So, it should work. `setDT(DT)[..`

Comment: @akrun: ah ok! but `setDT(DT)`...? what do you mean? you mean `setnames`? or do you mean literally typying `setDT(DT)[!duplicated(paste(pmin(V1, V2),pmax(V1,V2)))] `

Comment: @Javier I meant if your `DT` object was `data.frame`, it should be converted to `data.table`.  By typing that, I get the subset

Comment: @akrun. Yeah sorry, I am silly, just re-started R and did not load data.table.  ¬¬ . Thanks again!

Comment: @Javier If you can show the benchmarks in your post, it would be great.

Comment: @akrun: you mean a comparison of the system.time measurements??

Comment: @Javier `microbenchmark` would be more informative on a bigger dataset.  But system.time gives some info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find these, you can use some data.table functions, like this:

```
> dt <- data.table(V1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "N","P"), V2 = c("B","C","A","F","P","N"))
> dt
   V1 V2
1:  A  B
2:  A  C
3:  B  A
4:  B  F
5:  N  P
6:  P  N
> dt1 <- dt[, paste0(V1, V2)]
> dt1
[1] "AB" "AC" "BA" "BF" "NP" "PN"
> dt2 <- dt[, paste0(V2, V1)]
> dt2
[1] "BA" "CA" "AB" "FB" "PN" "NP"
> matches <- data.table(m = match(dt1, dt2))
> matches
    m
1:  3
2: NA
3:  1
4: NA
5:  6
6:  5
> which(matches[, .I > m])
[1] 3 6
```

I'm using the `match()` function, which is REALLY fast. So first I'm making these into character vectors both ways. Then I'm finding where the first character vector is found in the second one for the first time (I know it's confusing sentence). I want to make the result a data.table once again to utilize the `.I` there. I made a data.table with 600 000 rows and all of it worked in less than a second.

Comment: Hi Laurik. Thanks. Someone in the comments pointed towards another answer that also solved my question. I attach it here in case is of any use to you. Is very similar to your approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756392/deleting-reversed-duplicates-with-r . Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah. Depends on the size of the data. Solutions based on data.frame will work fairly fast with everything up to a few hundred thousand rows. Once you get to millions of rows, you really need data.table (and/or plyr/dplyr). It's been quite a learning curve for myself, but I've found that learning data.table package tricks is very beneficial.