# Removing reverse duplicate rows

Tags: r, performance, duplicates, data.table

I have a `data.table` with two columns of genes and each row treated as a pair. Some gene pairs are duplicated with the order reversed. I am looking for a faster method, preferably without using a loop like the one I've provided, to keep unique pairs in my table.

```
library(data.table)
genes <- data.table(geneA = LETTERS[1:10], geneB = c("C", "G", "B", "E", "D", "I", "H", "J", "F", "A"))

revG <- genes[,.(geneA = geneB, geneB = geneA)]
d <- fintersect(genes, revG)

for (x in 1:nrow(d)) {
  entry <- d[,c(geneA[x], geneB[x])]; revEntry <- rev(entry)
  dupEntry <- d[geneA %chin% revEntry[1] & geneB %chin% revEntry[2]]
  if (nrow(dupEntry) > 0) {
    d <- d[!(geneA %chin% dupEntry[,geneA] & geneB %chin% dupEntry[,geneB])]
  }
}
```

The table object `d` contains the duplicated, reversed pairs. After the loop, one copy of each is remaining. I used the original genes table and took a subset, excluding the copies in `d` and storing the index. I have a list whose names are the same as the first column in `genes`. The index is used to filter the list based on the duplicate pairs that were removed with the loop.

```
idx <- genes[!(geneA %chin% d[,geneA] & geneB %chin% d[,geneB]), which = TRUE]

geneList <- vector("list", length = nrow(genes)); names(geneList) <- genes[,geneA]
geneList <- geneList[idx]
```

The above method isn't necessarily too slow, but I plan on using ~12K genes so the speed might be noticeable then. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756392/deleting-reversed-duplicates-with-r) with the same problem posted but without using `data.table`. It uses an `apply` function to get the job done but that might also be slow when dealing with larger numbers.

Comment: You can try `unique(d[,list(geneA=do.call(pmin,d),geneB=do.call(pmax,d))])`, but it works only if you have two columns (it should be ok for you).

Comment: You can apply the method of @nicola also directly to `genes`. It will give the same result and you don't need to create `revG` and `d`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, what you are asking is similar to, given a list of permutations by 2, how can I get the combinations. 
This can be an option, using `igraph`.

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)
genes <- data.table(geneA = LETTERS[1:10], geneB = c("C", "G", "B", "E", "D", "I", "H", "J", "F", "A"))
g <-graph_from_data_frame(genes, directed = F)
g <- simplify(g, remove.multiple = T, remove.loops = T)
get.data.frame(g)
  from to
1    A  C
2    A  J
3    B  C
4    B  G
5    D  E
6    F  I
7    G  H
8    H  J

#benchmark
set.seed(1283782)
fn1<-function(genes){
  g <-graph_from_data_frame(genes, directed = F)
  g <- simplify(g, remove.multiple = T, remove.loops = T)
  get.data.frame(g)}
genes <- data.table(geneA = sample(LETTERS, 20000, T), geneB = sample(LETTERS, 20000, T))
microbenchmark(fn1(genes), times = 1)
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 fn1(genes) 8.605717 8.605717 8.605717 8.605717 8.605717 8.605717     1
```